# Access 2010: Embedding a form into a navigation form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form called **ClientSearch** which provides basic search on three fields into the ***Clients*** Table and displays results. This form is bound to the **Clients** table (Record Source is set to "Client" for the form). To search the ***Clients*** table, my code uses a ***DoCmd.ApplyFilter*** command in the event handler for the search button.

I then made a navigation form and dragged the ***ClientSearch*** form into one of its categories.

Now, when I click the search button, my ***DoCmd.ApplyFilter*** does not work anymore. I get a runtime error telling me my form is not bound to a particular table which is true. The navigation form is not bound to any tables and it can't be, since there will be multiple embedded forms on it for different tables and queries. 
How do I address this problem? It seems that Access and VBA have no idea which table to use for the ***ApplyFilter*** query.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the way that people go about searching is to create a query that contains the fields with the criteria related to another text field. for example criteria for [First Name] might be:

```
Like [Forms]![frm_RecordSearch]![txtFirst] & "*"
```

That will show all results if the text box is blank and allow for people to search based on partial matches.
From there all you would need to do is create a form based on the query and have the form with the search criteria call the display form. This will automatically sort it. If you want to avoid closing the form each time you search again you can also use Me.requery for example with two forms the search form would look like:

```
Private Sub cmdb_search_Click()
If CurrentProject.AllForms("frm_SearchResults").IsLoaded Then
Forms![frm_SearchResults].Form.Requery
Else
DoCmd.OpenForm "frm_SearchResults"
End If
End Sub
```

As well you can use a similar technique to sort using sub forms though where the subform is the results and the text boxes/combo boxes etc. are contained on the main form and have an after update requery or search button etc that triggers the search. The downside of this method is the form is not able to be continuous as far as I know, but you can still get a good result this way.

I hope that helps. Let me know if anything is unclear!